# How do I get the filename of the currently playing file in Vista Media Center?

Tags: c#, .net, mcml

I have Windows Vista MCML app, and I need to figure out the current name of the file playing.

The Media Center SDK alludes to using MediaMetadata["Title"] to get this information, unfortunately this does not work with playlists (.wpl) files as there is no method for getting the position in the playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this [can not be easily done](http://discuss.mediacentersandbox.com/forums/thread/8436.aspx).

There are 4 options.

1. Never use play lists, in that case MediaMetadata["Title"] is good enough.
2. Examine remote file handles in ehshell.exe.
3. Inject a remote thread in ehshell.exe, establish communication and use reflection to read it.
4. Write a DirectShow filter and communicate with it.

**Update**: This is fixed in [Windows 7](http://blog.retrosight.com/CommentView,guid,5D241B55-68E8-44FA-B64C-4E031CE053E3.aspx#f64ba952-da91-4240-b7bd-f29fdc51887c). It is unclear if its going to be back ported to Vista MCE yet.

**Second Update**: Looks like Microsoft have changed the behavior of MediaMetadata["Title"] in a recent hotfix, it now returns both the filename without an extension and the playlist name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
MediaContext.GetProperty(TrackTitle)
```

I've also seen samples that in the markup for the media display layout file they specify an element such as:

```
<music-title duration = "2000" x="69" y="29" width="187" height="20"/>
```

Good Luck!